# Synchronized objects accessed from unsynchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose I have a class in which there is a StringBuffer declared as a member variable. Two threads are trying to manipulate the object like below

```
public class SomeService {

    private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    public void printName(String name) {
        sb.append(name);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}

public class StringBufferSynchronizationTest implements Runnable {

    private SomeService service = new SomeService();

    public StringBufferSynchronizationTest() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new StringBufferSynchronizationTest().service.printName("oops");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        service.printName("java");
    }
}
```

And I get this output

```
oopsjava
oopsjava
```

I thought I will get

```
oops
oopsjava
```

as output. When I synchronized printName method I got the second output.

So I understood that even I use a synchronized class I have to synchronize blocks/methods that use the synchronized classes. Am I right?

Comment: yes you have to use  sychronized method

Comment: *First* you must know what you want, *then* you start thinking how to get it. Each method call on `StringBuffer` is synchronized on its own, which clearly has nothing to do with the interleaving of  separate method calls.

Comment: I believe if you run this enough times you will eventually get your expected output. It's a race condition.

Comment: So what is the use of having synchronized StringBuffer. I can synchronize blocks/methods in my code. It is the same right?

Comment: @Cruncher Yeah I also believe in the same. But I want on output which is similar to the second one, always.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya The synchronized StringBuffer just makes all StringBuffer operations atomic. Which it's doing. Like Marko said, you need to know what you want to do it before you can start working toward it,

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya in *this* case, making printName synchronized will do it. this makes the entire printName operation atomic, which is what you really want. It stops the context switch from happening between append and print. edit: Actually there would be a change of getting java\njavaoops if you synchronize it. There's more you would have to do to guarentee what you want.

Comment: I think the biggest thing to take away from all of this, is to try to understand what synchronized means, and **what** you need synchronized. Don't just assume things work the way you want because the documentation says they're "synchronized".

Comment: I replaced `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` and synchronized printName method. I always see `oops\noopsjava` output. I dont see any use of having a StringBuffer class or my understading about synchronization is wrong and I need to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuffer guarantees that only one thread can enter append or any other method of the same instance. But this is all, there are no more guarantees.

Comment: Well, it also guarantees that if two threads both call `append` (or other synchronised `StringBuffer` methods) on the same instance, there will be a happens-before relationship. :-)

Comment: StringBuffer guarantees that its methods are executed in a *sequentially consistent* manner. This covers both mutual exclusion and *happens-before*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the StringBuffer is synchronized, If you want the expected result, synchronized also the function printName. Context switch can be occur between `sb.append(name);` and `System.out.println(sb);` especially it is related to slow IO.

```
public synchronized void printName(String name) {
    sb.append(name);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Let us take a look at `printName`

```
public void printName(String name) {
    sb.append(name);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Since sb in synchronized, `sb.append(name)` has only 1 thread operating on the objects mutable state. This prevents Strings, in your example, of the values

```
oojavaps
ojopsava
```

and so on. However since your printName method is not synchronized you have no guarantees on the order of invocation of the 2 methods within printName across 2 threads.

The easiest way to understand it is probably to come up with the sequence of execution that results in the output

```
oopsjava
oopsjava
```

Initially `sb` is the empty String

Assume the main thread executes `sb.append(name)`, leaving `sb` with `oops`, however it is preempted before it can execute the `println`

The constructor thread takes over and execute the entire method, first appending `java` to `sb` to get `oopsjava` in `sb` and then printing the output, to get

```
oopsjava
```

The main thread then executes, printing `sb` to get

```
oopsjava
```

I had one example of output here that was incorrect, @Cruncher pointed this out in the comments and I removed it.

Comment: `This prevents Strings, in your example, of the values`---actually, it prevents much deeper trouble than that, like the destruction of `StringBuffer`'s internal invariants. Such things would be a legitimate outcome of unsynchronized method calls.

Comment: I don't see how `oops\njava` is a possible outcome. StringBuffer is synchronized, and you append. There is no way it can get through both append calls, and "delete" the first append in this code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you comments misses the point that is being made. I have no intention of listing all possible error mode is StringBuffer were not synchronized.

Comment: I am making my own point beside yours because I deem that point important in understanding what a data race is about. Reasoning about code while minding only the mild cases you indicate will result in undersynchronization and broken code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, I see, fair enough you are correct too

Comment: While on the subject, your examples like `oojavaps` are an *impossible* outcome for any interleaving of threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and my post says as much.

Comment: I mean, impossible *even in the absence of any synchronization*. Impossible in the case of using a `StringBuilder`, if you will.

Comment: It is easy to prove if you inspect the source code. The `count` instance variable is not updated for each character written, but after the complete string has been written. The characters are copied in one go, without consulting `count` for each char. This is why `append("oops")` and `append("java")` could possibly *overwrite* each other, but interleaving is impossible.

Comment: `The characters are copied in one go` using `System.arrayCopy` while your assumption that this done is one go without interleaving is reasonable and possibly true, there is no JVM specification that requires the same, the signature of the method is `public static native void`. I agree that the output I provided as examples are not likely, but there are not constrained by the specification to not occur.

Besides, they serve as useful exposition for the purposes of answering the question at hand.

Comment: You have missed the point... interleaving of execution will not result in the interleaving of characters. It will result in *overwriting* characters. You may get `oova` or `japs` etc. but not your examples.